# Problema com um campo em RegEX

Tags: .net, regex

Tenho a seguinte expressão:

```
(?!.*");
```

ela captura tudo o que estiver separado pelo caractere `;` exceto quando ta dentro de uma string. Aqui vai um exemplo:

```
ABC;            #captura o último ;
123;            #captura o último ;
"XYZ";          #captura o último ;
"A B; C";       #captura apenas o último ; não o que está dentro da string
"Uma string     #
 com ; várias   #esse aqui é capturado
 linhas;";      #captura o último ;
```

Vamos analisar esse último item da lista:

```
"Uma string
 com ;(1) várias
 linhas;(2)";(3)
```

E o que é retornado são os ponto e vírgula **1** e **3**.
Onde está o erro? Como resolvo? *prefiro a resposta com compartibilidade com o .NET Framework*

Comment: Esses exemplos sao o que a regex *faz* ou o que *devia fazer*? Primeiro dizes que a regex captura "tudo o que estiver separado pelo caracter `;`", mas depois ja dizes que a regex apenas captura os `;`. Tenta explicar melhor o que acontece *agora* e o que *queres que aconteca*.

Comment: Esses exemplos ta mostrando que ele fez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você está procurando é o parâmetro `RegexOptions.Singleline`, com esse parametro a expressão regular é interpretada como uma única linha.

```
Regex.Matches(input, "(?!.*\");", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Eu fiz um exemplo no [DotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ObH36v)